# In Expo Cli using facebook login I got alert of already read exception

Tags: react-native, oauth, facebook-oauth, expo

[This Type of Exception Occurs While implementating expo facebook signin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8mUT.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have called `response.json()` more than once after `fetch()`. You can save the value in a variable instead of call multiple times.